# jquery change() does not work with jquery autocomplete for same html element

Tags: jquery

I have an input field which is binded to jquery UI auto complete. On selecting a particular entry from the drop down in auto complete, some is received at the client side and then set as values to some other fields. It works fine.But when I write something in the field as the value and expect to receive those data, I dont get them. I dont know how to do this.

My second question is, to solve this problem I binded the same input field with jquery change(). On change, the specific values are set to some other fields, but instantly yhey disappear from the fields. I cant understand what the problem is. My code is here.

```
                $("#siteID1").autocomplete({
                        source: "sourceSearch.php?field=site",
                        minLength: 1,

                        focus: function(event, ui) { 
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                        },

                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $(this).val(ui.item.label);

                        },
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            if(ui.item!=null)
                            {
                                $("#site1Name").val(ui.item.value.btsName);
                                $("#site1Long").val(ui.item.value.longitude);
                                $("#site1Lat").val(ui.item.value.latitude);
                                $("#site1CId").val(ui.item.value.componentId);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#site1Name").val("");
                                $("#site1Long").val("");
                                $("#site1Lat").val("");
                                $("#site1CId").val("");
                            }


                        }   
               });
```

The above code is when I bind an autocomplete with the field. The following code is when I bind the field with change().

```
               $('#siteID1').change(function() {
                    $.ajax({            
                              url: "sourceSearch.php?field=site&term="+$('#siteID1').val(),
                              dataType: 'json',
                              //async: false,
                              success:  function(data){

                                    if(data)
                                    {
                                        $("#site1Name").val(data[0].value.btsName);
                                        $("#site1Long").val(data[0].value.longitude);
                                        $("#site1Lat").val(data[0].value.latitude);
                                        $("#site1CId").val(data[0].value.componentId);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $("#site1Name").val("");
                                        $("#site1Long").val("");
                                        $("#site1Lat").val("");
                                        $("#site1CId").val("");
                                    }


                              }
                        }); 
                });
```

In both cases, I get receive the json data from server accurately. But on change, "btesName", "longitude" etc disappear as soon as they are set as the values. Can anyone please help me??

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the line

```
    $('#siteID1').change(function()
```

to this:

```
    $('#siteID1').live('change' ,function()
```

Does that help at all?

Also have you put an alert in the else statement just in case its triggering that when it shouldnt be?